# Can't get django registration to work

Tags: django, django-registration

i have installed django-registration on django 1.3, I can't get it to work.

When i hit submit on the accounts/register/ page, it redirects to accounts/registration which isn't in the default URL's.

I can't seem to pass my post data to the register function.  Help?

Comment: Can you say what you did, be more specific in what error messages you are receiving, etc. if your issue has not been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Does your urls.py have:

```
import registration
...
urlpatterns += patterns(
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Do you have all the appropriate templates installed in a template directory?

https://github.com/yourcelf/django-registration-defaults